# wxWidgets menu bar doesn't show up

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am trying to create a simple program with a menu using wxWidgets. However, the menu doesn't seem to be appearing properly.

This is my code:

helloworld.hpp:

```
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

#include "TextFrame.hpp"

class HelloWorldApp : public wxApp {
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

DECLARE_APP(HelloWorldApp)
```

helloworld.cpp:

```
#include "helloworld.hpp"

IMPLEMENT_APP(HelloWorldApp)

bool HelloWorldApp::OnInit() {
    TextFrame *frame = new TextFrame(_T("Hi"), 200, 200, 800, 600);

    frame->CreateStatusBar();
    frame->SetStatusText(_T("Hello, World!"));

    frame->Show(true);
    SetTopWindow(frame);

    return true;
}
```

TextFrame.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <wx/wxprec.h>

#ifndef WX_PREC
    #include <wx/wx.h>
#endif

class TextFrame : public wxFrame {
public:

    /** Constructor. Creates a new TextFrame */
    TextFrame(const wxChar *title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height);

private:

    wxTextCtrl *m_pTextCtrl;
    wxMenuBar *m_pMenuBar;
    wxMenu *m_pFileMenu;
    wxMenu *m_pHelpMenu;
};
```

TextFrame.cpp:

```
#include "TextFrame.hpp"

TextFrame::TextFrame(const wxChar *title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height)
    : wxFrame((wxFrame *) NULL, -1, title, wxPoint(xpos, ypos), wxSize(width, height))
{
    m_pTextCtrl = new wxTextCtrl(this, -1, _T("Type some text..."),
                       wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTE_MULTILINE);

    m_pMenuBar = new wxMenuBar();
    // File Menu
    m_pFileMenu = new wxMenu();
    m_pFileMenu->Append(wxID_OPEN, _T("&Open"));
    m_pFileMenu->Append(wxID_SAVE, _T("&Save"));
    m_pFileMenu->AppendSeparator();
    m_pFileMenu->Append(wxID_EXIT, _T("&Quit"));
    m_pMenuBar->Append(m_pFileMenu, _T("&File"));
    // About menu
    m_pHelpMenu = new wxMenu();
    m_pHelpMenu->Append(wxID_ABOUT, _T("&About"));
    m_pMenuBar->Append(m_pHelpMenu, _T("&Help"));

    SetMenuBar(m_pMenuBar);
}
```

This code comes (for the most part) directly from [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Adding_A_Menubar).

It compiles successfully (using `` g++ TextFrame.cpp helloworld.cpp `wx-config -cxxflags --libs` -o helloworld ``), but when I run it I see the default menu, and not the custom one I tried to add.

I tried out the "menu" sample and that works fine, so I think I'm doing something wrong here.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: which platform? Can you add you modification to the minimal sample?

Comment: also- what is different from the menu sample? Can you make the sample so that it doesn't display the menu?

Comment: Huh, my earlier comment seems to have disappeared. I am on a Mac. I'll try comparing it to the menu sample and adding it to the minimal one.